# how to kill an app in android emulator using keyboard keys

Tags: android, key, emulation

I want to stop/kill my running application in android emulator using any keyboard shortcut, but failed to find any key, can anyone tell me about that key.!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do that BY command line check this please https://devmaze.wordpress.com/2011/12/12/starting-and-stopping-android-emulators/

Or by these steps:

1. Click on “DDMS”
2. Select the application you want to kill
3. Click on “Stop”

more explanation on image: 
[image]

hope this help!!

Comment: i want to do this using keyboard, like to go back we can press "Esc" key, like that i want to know about kill shortcut key.

Comment: mmm I don't know the specific key to do that as Home key on real device BUT you can do that Inside the emulator go to the Settings app, then Applications -> Manage Applications -- you can delete them from there.

Answer (score 0):

Here is some keyboard command for android emulator [Android developer](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/emulator.html)

hope this will help you.